# caption set to display:none in lightbox image

Tags: show, caption, display

I have added the attribute "data-title=" to my lightbox images, but when I inspect the code the caption has 'display:none;'

I just need to find out how to show the caption - any ideas please?

Lightbox is at http://physio-joint.co.uk/bobg/ref-sites/barn.htm

Thanks for any help!

Comment: you can give 'title=text' instead of 'data-title=', currently lb-caption div is empty

Comment: Yes I see that lb-caption div is empty, but I can' figure out how to get the "title-text" into it!  What do I need to change in the .js (or .css) files??

Comment: I clearly need to do something to stop this:  <span class="lb-caption" style="display: none;"></span>

Comment: in lightbox.css, add end of line .lb-data .lb-caption { display:block !important; }